# Loading <script> tag under html <body> tag from <head>

Tags: javascript, html

I have need to add javascript that would run on page `<head>`. I have no possibility to edit page `<head> </head>`. There is also no possibility to add the code manually in the beginning of `<body>`.However I found way to insert the code bellow to run inside other code that runs already in HTML header, but the script conflicts with other scripts, because my code inserts itself in the beginning of `<head>` part.

```
var nexus=['Bootstrap.js'];
for(i=0;i<nexus.length;i++){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = nexus[i];
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

How do I modify the code to insert the script in the beginning of page `<BODY>` or the line before header ending tag `</HEAD>`? Now the problem is that the code cannot detect `<body>`, cause it's not loaded before  loads. There is also requirement that the code must be able to run with IE7+.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);` inserts script before header ending tag `</head>`.

Comment: Why does it need to be in the head? The usual reason for that is so the script is available before the rest of the page loads - but that won't be the case if you are dynamically adding it after the rest of the page has loaded.

Comment: I'm making page A/B testing, so the external JS-script controls the page content by replacing it in specific conditions. The code needs to be placed to the beginning of body or in the ending of head. Now the code has been inserted to the bottom of page, so the content is replaced after the page load.

Comment: @dfsq Somehow Firebug shows the code in the beginning of head, when using document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);